# I have success message but no email received in my forgot password laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, forgot-password

This my success message but no email received in my email box

[image]

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

i use mail_client instead of email so i override some function , also i add in my client model this->mail_client

```
class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller{
use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('mail_client')
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
        : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{$this->validate($request, ['mail_client' => 'required|email']);
}


protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return back()->withErrors(
        ['mail_client' => trans($response)]
    );
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the answer : first i need override that method (getEmailForPasswordReset and routeNotificationFor) into model Client:

```
public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->mail_client;
}

public function routeNotificationFor($driver)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method = 'routeNotificationFor'.Str::studly($driver))) {
        return $this->{$method}();
    }

    switch ($driver) {
        case 'database':
            return $this->notifications();
        case 'mail':
            return $this->mail_client;
        case 'nexmo':
            return $this->phone_number;
    }
}
```

and implement:

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Str
```

into ForgotPasswordController need override the method called sendResetLinkEmail ,validateEmail and sendResetLinkFailedResponse:

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('mail_client')
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['mail_client' => 'required|email']);
    }

    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return back()->withErrors(
            ['mail_client' => trans($response)]
        );
    }
```

And dont forget to chage name input in your blade .
That's all .

Answer (score 0):

Have you postfix installed ?

try to check if the function mail() works successfully;

Probably you can use maildev for development part.

Comment: Why should postfix be installed if the mail is sent using SMTP?

Comment: The problem was not there , i must override the function (routeNotificationFor) like i mention below

Answer (score 0):

Problem: **This my success message but no email received in my email box. This problem faced in Laravel 10.1.X**

Solution:  **How i solved.**

After a lot of RND, I found this solution. It worked.
Add this line to .env file. You just write your own sender email.

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
```